# jqGrid and jqPivot: How to sumary pivot column specify in ydimension and aggregates with count method?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqpivot

I'm using jqGrid with the jqPivot.

Here my code:

```
$("#pvtCrewAttendance").jqGrid("jqPivot",
            data,
            {
                footerTotals: true,
                footerAggregator: "sum",
                totals: true,
                totalText: "Sumary",
                xDimension: [
                    { dataName: "CategoryName", label: "Category Name", sortorder: "desc", footerText: "Row total" },
                ],
                yDimension: [
                    { dataName: "ProductName", sorttype: "text", totalHeader: "Total in {0}" },
                ],
                aggregates: [
                    { member: "ProductName", aggregator: "count" }
                ]
            },
            // grid options
            {
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, width: 80 },
                shrinkToFit: false,
                autoresizeOnLoad: true,
                autoResizing: { compact: true },
                pager: false,
                rowNum: 20,
                width: 420,
                height: 100,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100, "10000:All"],
                caption: "Selling statistic"
            }
        );
```

This my plunk
[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZckWtEi1CFxW2zMObiQD?p=preview)

I want to sumary quantity of product for each category in the last column.

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug in [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.2/js/grid.pivot.js#L439) of code `jqPivot`. I'll fix it in the next days. As a workaround I suggest you to use `aggregator` defined as function:

```
aggregates: [
    {
        member: "ProductName",
        template: "integer",
        aggregator: function (options) {
            // do the same like aggregator: "count"
            return options.previousResult + 1;
        }
    }
]
```

The corresponding demo https://plnkr.co/edit/fz66phRoOLXWOuqTxF8g?p=preview displays

[image]

with "Cols total" column having correct **count** results.

Comment: Great @Oleg, thank you very much. This problem has taken more than a day for me. @_@

Comment: a small question more: Is there any way to bold the value of "Cols total" column

Comment: @Tommy1209: You are welcome! You can make the last column bold in different way. For example, the header of the total column have the name "t" and id of the column header built from grid id and the column name: `pvtCrewAttendance_t`. The cells of the column have attribute `aria-describedby=pvtCrewAttendance_t`. Thus one can use CSS rule `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow>td[aria-describedby=pvtCrewAttendance_t], #pvtCrewAttendance_t { font-weight: bold; }`. See https://plnkr.co/edit/aWcjSYr7r7D3iw7jTTMv?p=preview